# Cannot find class when refrencing from another project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cross-platform, libgdx

I have looked at the following which I thought would work but it did not.

> [Could not find class XXX referenced from method XXX.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14765910/could-not-find-class-xxx-referenced-from-method-xxx-yyy)
>
> [Hello world, libgdx crashes on phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968064/hello-world-libgdx-crashes-on-phone)
>
> [Android Libgx Frogger game crashing: Could not find class 'com.rengelbert.froggergdx.FroggerGame'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982110/android-libgx-frogger-game-crashing-could-not-find-class-com-rengelbert-frogge?rq=1)

My main diffrence between all the other questions is that I did not create the android project when I created the desktop project which I create with the Gdx-setup.jar. I decided to make an android project quite a bit after I created the desktop version.

I am getting the error:

```
08-23 05:30:09.341: E/dalvikvm(27497): Could not find class 'com.cvgstudios.pokemonchrome.ChromeGame', referenced from method com.cvgstudios.pokemonchrome.RunAndroidChrome.onCreate
08-23 05:30:09.341: W/dalvikvm(27497): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 1027 (Lcom/cvgstudios/pokemonchrome/ChromeGame;) in Lcom/cvgstudios/pokemonchrome/RunAndroidChrome;
08-23 05:30:09.341: D/dalvikvm(27497): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0014
08-23 05:30:09.341: D/dalvikvm(27497): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x2a07 at 0x16 in Lcom/cvgstudios/pokemonchrome/RunAndroidChrome;.onCreate
08-23 05:30:09.341: D/dalvikvm(27497): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.cvgstudios.pokemonchrome-1/libgdx.so 0x41a79df0
08-23 05:30:09.349: D/dalvikvm(27497): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.cvgstudios.pokemonchrome-1/libgdx.so 0x41a79df0
08-23 05:30:09.349: D/dalvikvm(27497): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.cvgstudios.pokemonchrome-1/libgdx.so 0x41a79df0, skipping init
08-23 05:30:09.357: D/AndroidRuntime(27497): Shutting down VM
08-23 05:30:09.357: W/dalvikvm(27497): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41809700)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cvgstudios.pokemonchrome/com.cvgstudios.pokemonchrome.RunAndroidChrome}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    at com.cvgstudios.pokemonchrome.RunAndroidChrome.onCreate(RunAndroidChrome.java:17)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2293)
08-23 05:30:09.364: E/AndroidRuntime(27497):    ... 11 more
```

As you can see the error is that

> Could not find class 'com.cvgstudios.pokemonchrome.ChromeGame',
>   referenced from method
>   com.cvgstudios.pokemonchrome.RunAndroidChrome.onCreate

While looking around to find the answer to my dilema a possible solution was to make sure it was exporting the main project properly. I fixed that:

[image: Android Project exporting the main project]

However the problem still persists.

I've checked everything all of the order and export boxes, in desktop, main and android project's buildpaths.

This is my class

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;

public class RunAndroidChrome extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = true;

        Gdx.app.log(ChromeGame.LOG,
                "Attempting to make Android Chrome Work");
        initialize(new com.cvgstudios.pokemonchrome.ChromeGame(), cfg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your RunAndroidChrome class...

Comment: did you added any new jars ..??

Comment: @Dileep: all the ones that i'm supposed to

Comment: @Exikle what about buid path..??

Answer (score 0):

> There is an ***import missing*** in your Class `RunAndroidChrome`

```
import com.cvgstudios.pokemonchrome.ChromeGame;
```

Usually the IDE automatically import the depended Class.

If that is not a class defined by you, then the you must have forgot to **Add Build Path**..
Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327434/how-to-add-the-jar-file-into-the-build-path) for how to add Build Path.

> One another possibility is that you might have tested that in a wrong
>   machine.

Also in `cfg.useGL20 = true;` we tell Android to use OpenGL ES 2. This means we will be able to test it only on a device as the emulator does not support OpenGL ES 2. In case there is a problem with it, switch this to false.

**Check [this](http://obviam.net/index.php/getting-started-in-android-game-development-with-libgdx-create-a-working-prototype-in-a-day-tutorial-part-1/) Link for more information**

Comment: unfortunately it still does it

Comment: @Exikle where did u tested it..??

Comment: @Exikle Look into my new answer, may be that helps..!!